# Python https request Errno 11004 getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

Im new to python and trying to make a standard http request with my code being only this:

```
    import requests
    requests.get('https://github.com')
```

but i always get tracebacks which basicly tell me:

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
...
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

im working behind a corporate firewall. I guess it's somehow interferring. Do I need to add a proxy or something like that?

Comment: Does not reproduce for me. Try `import socket` and then `socket.gethostbyname("https://github.com")`

Comment: I think @Seer.The meant `socket.gethostbyname('github.com') `as he's trying to see if DNS resolves.